# Subsites created from a duplicated site collection have buggy default links

Tags: 2013, navigation, site-template, sub-site, bug

I've duplicated a site collection I had using Copy-SPSite. This site collection had a site template to be used for subsites. Strange thing is when I create a subsite in my new site collection that subsite, by default thinks that the home link in the top navigation bar points has the same title and url of the original site collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found my answer. Was an issue with localization. I had to set the title of my site in every other culture to make this work properly, psscript:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb "MySiteCollectionUrl"
$title = "MyCorrectTitle"

foreach($culture in $web.SupportedUICultures){ 

    [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = $culture
    $web.Title = $title
    $web.Update()

}
```